# 'end' expected (to close 'if' at line 1) near 'until' how do i fix it?

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

```
if SERVER then 
    until.addnetworkstring ("F4menu")
    
    function F4menufunc(ply)
        net.start("F4menu")
        net.send(ply)
    end
    book.Add("Showspare4", "F4menuHook", F4menufunc)
end 

if CLIENT then 
    net.receive("F4menu", function()
        if (!frame) then
            local frame = vgui.create("Dframe")
            frame:SetSize(1000,720)
            frame:Center()
            frame:SetVisible(true)
            frame:MakePopup()
            frame:SetDeleteOnClose(true)
        end
    end)
end
```

Im new to code and am unsure what is wrong here. I'm trying to make a popup menu in Gmod. When i run it in gmod it comes up with this: 'end' expected (to close 'if' at line 1) near 'until'

Thanks

Comment: `until` is a keyword in Lua.  You can not have a variable with name `until`.  May be you meant `util.AddNetworkString()` ?

Comment: Oh I thought the problem was something else. Didn't realise the until. It was supposed to be util. Thanks haha

Answer (score 0):

It was answered in the comments, but your code has a lot of typos.

- `until.addnetworkstring` should be `util.AddNetworkString`
- `net.start` should be `net.Start`
- `net.send` should be `net.Send`
- `book.Add` is actually `hook.Add`
- there is also no hook Showspare4, you probably mean ShowSpare2

and a lot more stuff where you put lowercase instead of uppercase

You also don't need to network any of that. The hook `ShowSpare2` is available shared, so you can just add it on the client and leave the networking out of it